# addEventListener is not a function error in javascript

Tags: javascript, typeerror, addeventlistener

while working with eventListeners in JavaScript, I have came accross an error.

```
trials.htm:54 Uncaught TypeError: b.addEventListner is not a function
```

Here's my HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="icard">Hover Me</button>
</body>
<script>
  function hover() {
    console.log("Hovered!!!");
  }
  let b = document.getElementById("icard");
  b.addEventListner("mouseover", hover());
</script>

</html>
```

I have added the script tag after body to ensure that it excecutes only after the DOM has loaded.

So what's the problem with it?????

Comment: `addEventListner` missing an `e` - also, you need to add a function for the handler, not call a function for the handler - voting to close as a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its addEventListener, just a spelling mistake

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. They don't have value for the site. The normal approach is to close the question and leave a comment (when you have rep). Thanks.